# How to add unique entries in google spreadsheet by using google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am adding the rows in the spreadsheet by using ajax request.

Google spreadsheet script:

```js
function doGet(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

function handleResponse(e) {
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);
  
  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = []; 

    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(new Datetime());
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);

    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}

function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

I am adding new entry by using fetch method:

```js
fetch('https://script.google.com/macros/s/______token_____/exec?orderId=108&Text=this+is+text',{mode:'no-cors'});
```

However, I want to add only unique rows based on the orderId parameter

Comment: Could you include in your question a photo of the data that you have? It would be really helpful if you did.

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem but I noticed that you don't use headRow in the second line here.  So it's always one. `var headRow=e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers=sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];`

Comment: Can you share a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on?